# Not able to load javascript files in webbrowser in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, webbrowser-control

In one of my Windows Phone application I am using webbrowser to display the html content. I am getting the html content by making post request to server. Here I am getting the response correctly.Then I am displaying this response in webbrowser by,

webBrowser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
   webBrowser.NavigateToString(responseString);

The response is:

```
<html>
<HEAD>
<script language='JavaScript'>
</script>
<SCRIPT language='JavaScript' src='script/page.js'></SCRIPT>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="js/page2.js"></script>
</HEAD>
<BODY  onload='someFunction()'>
 <div>
-- 
<img src='Images/loader.gif' /><br /><br />
--
</div>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

From here I am not able to call the page.js file, page2.js file and not able get the loader.gif image also. I think this is because the files are not locally stored.
I also tried by saving the response in Isolatedstorage as .html file. and displaying it 
by using,

```
webBrowser.IsScriptEnabled = true;
webBrowser.Navigate(uri);
```

but here also I am getting same thing.
Please help me to get resolve this issue. Thanks in adcvance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scripts and images aren't loaded, because paths to it in the html are *relative*. When you save it to a file, the scripts and image should be in relative locations to that file.

You should use `webBrowser.Navigate` with the `Uri` of the web page *on the net* (don't download it yourself, let the browser do it). Or the html has to have the full paths, like: `<img src='http://contoso.com/Images/loader.gif' />`.

Comment: Hi lisp, Thank you for your reply.
 Actually I am calling an api which includes some parameters and it is a post request, that returns me html content as a response. That response I am taking it as a string and loading into webbrowser.

And to handle some other issue I also tried by saving the response as a .html file in storage, and then by using that uri I am displaying the content with webBrowser.Navigate.